# Pushing Files to GitHub using Git Gui Problems With Arbitrary Location AKA Destination Repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, git-gui

So I'm very new to git GUI, and was assigned the task to push files from my project onto github.  I opened the git GUI and opened up my project.  Then I clicked on all of the files that I want to stage change commit.  After that I clicked push and it ask for Arbitrary Location.  I have a repository on my github account, if that's relevant, but I still don't know what to type in.

Comment: Sure that's what it asked for? I am rather doubting that. I would expect it asked you for repository location. Look again.

Comment: it says destination repository and then under that it has arbitrary location

Comment: I still don't believe it. There is as far as I can find no such terminology in git or any git client. Post a screenshot.

Comment: It's after you click push, it might be because it's the latest version of git gui

Comment: Well, I see from the answer's link that that is indeed what they have chosen to call that field. That seems like the most confusing name they could possibly have put on it...

Answer (score 2):

The `arbitrary location` is the location of the remote repository, for example `git@github.com:user1/foo.git`.

You need to configure ssh-keys, if not already done. You may find more information at [An Illustrated Guide to Git on Windows](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/tour.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found is:

- Open Git Gui > Remote > Add... >

Name: "Repo name"

Location: "https://github.com/user/repo.git" <- your repo URL

Press "Add", next time yoou want to PUSH your changes will find a dropdown with the remote repo